# Is there a way to automate a priority table in Google Sheets based on another table?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I have a shared sheet where I have people list their classes by priority like below:

```
StudentA  StudentB  StudentC  StudentD
Math      Math      Sci       Eng
Sci       Eng       Eng       Math
Eng       Sci       Math      Sci
```

And I have a second table which I am currently making manually based on the above data. I would like to ask if this can be somehow automated via formula/function to save me the time (as in reality I am dealing with way more students and classes).

There may also be times where a student does not select from all the class options (it's provided in a dropdown) and only has a few on their column.

```
Math                 Eng                 Sci
StudentA/StudentB    StudentD            StudentC
StudentD             StudentB/StudentC   StudentA
StudentC             StudentA            StudentB/StudentD
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reorder the starting data as follows :

[image]

Then use a formula with a filter and expand :

```
=join("/",
     FILTER($G$2:$G$13,
            $H$2:$H$13=$A8,$I$2:$I$13=B$7)
)
```

[image]

[Sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T5iwDLRL5BPApsQlDQAU4bZvyBxgIu_TTZSEZibj_0E/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't exactly the goal format you mentioned, i actually think it might be easier to keep track.

[Here is a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hpz8_Ev9Lervq3ErnBBP-mKKcz77DoymRPKb4tXNNhI/edit?usp=sharing).

This formula you'll find once for each class.  it will build the whole class in order of student priority with their priority numbers to the left of the name.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",TRUE,IF('By Student'!$B2:$E<>"",ROW('By Student'!$B2:$E)-1&"|"&'By Student'!$B1:$E1&"|"&'By Student'!$B2:$E,)),"#")),"|"),"select Col1,Col2 where Col3='"&A1&"' order by Col1"))
```